# SQL Server 2008 RS Roles multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a front end application needs access to 3 different SQL Server databases:

```
1st. database read/only
2nd. database read/write
3rd. database read/write
```

The user’s logins that will be using the database/application are using Windows authentication.

This application also calls a few SQL jobs that need to run.

What I would like to do is set up role to accomplish this and then easily map users to the role as needed.

Is there a way to do this in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Is there a better or easier approach?

I'm trying to avoid need to explicitly set up each user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an AD Group for your application. Get the DBA to hand out the appropriate permissions to the AD Group. Then have the Service-Desk add users to the AD Group as the business requires it.